# Second derivative of distance function to a point in model spaces.

Tags: geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry

I'm wondering if someone could please point me out to a reference (or the actual identity) where the following is shown.

Let $\gamma:I\to (\mathbb{R}^n,d=d_{euclidean})$ be a geodesic in $n$-Euclidean space and denote by $d_p:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ the distance function to a fixed point $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then it's easy to show that, for the function $f=d_p\circ \gamma:I\to \mathbb{R}$, the following holds (when everything is smooth):
$$f''f=1-f'^2 .$$

Does an analogous simple identity hold when considering the simply connected spaces of constant curvature $k$ rather than Euclidean space? 
(Of course, this should follow by finding some nice coordinates and computing to get the identity, but I figured I could ask and save myself some time).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This is false in other spaces $M$ of constant curvature. The reason is that $f$ is a 1-Lipschitz function (true in any Riemannian manifold) and, hence, $f'^2\le 1$. Hence, your identity implies that $f''\ge 0$. However, if $M$ has positive curvature, there are pairs $(p, \gamma)$ such that   $f$ is not convex (this is a good exercise which requires no computations, just pure thought). Hence, your identity cannot hold for the sphere. Using real-analyticity for distance function as a function of the curvature, one concludes that the identity cannot hold for hyperbolic spaces either.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes I know that the formula does not hold in positive or negatively curved spaces. In fact it just holds (locally) for flat spaces. The question was if there exist an analogous formula which characterizes spaces of constant curvature. And, well, there is but it looks a bit more elaborated.